# Replacing List items with Dictionary Items?

Tags: python

Does anyone know what I should be doing here? I'm new to python so I'm not quite sure how to describe it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Its sort of like a simple encrypter program.

I have a list (below), and a dictionary.

```
list = ['a','b','a','c','d','b']
dictionary = ('a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4)
```

And I want this output:

```
121342
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have a list and a syntax error

Comment: @DonkeyKong that's the thing - I don't know where to start really. I was messing around with Python and I sorta dug myself into a hole I'm too inexperienced to dig my way out of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_t = ['a','b','a','c','d','b']
dictionary = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
lis=[]
for i in list_t:
   for key in dictionary:
      if (i==key):
         lis.append(dictionary[i])
print lis
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
list = ['a','b','a','c','d','b']
dictionary = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}    
[dictionary[i] for i in list]
```

this expression will make new list by iterating on "list" variable and get "dictionary[i]" using "i" as every item in "list". Reed more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) about.

if you are not sure your "dictionary" have every value from "list" better to get "dictionary" values with "dictionary.get(i,'value if key is not found')". Then you can type:

```
[dictionary.get(i,'value if key is not found') for i in list]
```

[here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) you will get more about that

las one - if your result should be exact '121342', take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) then type

```
''.join([dictionary.get(i,'value if key is not found') for i in list])
```